# What will happen if constructor is not used in class in c++

Tags: c++

I am not enable to understand why constructor is used, it's functioning can be done through different method also by using "function". What constructor is able achieve in programming language that we can't achieve through function in c++. Instead if constructor we can use function also.

Main difference between constructor and function. What is the purpose of using constructor in  c++

Comment: initialize private members maybe?

Comment: Ordinary functions cannot create objects, only a constructor can do that, which functions merely call.

Comment: This seems like "why is C++ like C++". Constructors are early design decisions in the creation of the language.

Comment: Mostly this is just "syntactic sugar". Constructor is basically a function which is automatically called when object is created.

Comment: By some people a constructor is seen as "just syntactic sugar". But those fanatics often forget that most programming constructs, even those of that one language they worship, are a form of syntactic sugar.
A constructor gives a lot of guarantees upon object creation. you should read a good book on C++.

Comment: Getting past C-isms and learning about RAII will be very beneficial.

Comment: `int main() { int i; std::vector<int> vec; return 0; }` What do we know about `i`? What can we legally do with it? What do we know about `vec`? What can we legally do with it? That's what constructors get you: guaranteed initialization to a known state.

Comment: In C++, how would you construct an object if it has no constructor?  For example, `class Foo { int x; public: Foo() = delete; };`  Consider that in C++, a constructor is a sort of "factory function" that is tightly coupled to the class.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.   A constructor *is* a function.   It is a function that is automatically called in the process of initialising an object.

Comment: Why stop there? Everything you can accomplish with functions can be accomplished without them. Everything you can accomplish with structured loops can be acomplished with `goto`. Everything you can accomplish in a language with a type system can be acomplished in a language without one. And so on, ad nauseam...

Comment: @molbdnilo   You can even go further.   We don't need a any programming language other than assembler, because everything can be written in assembler.  Oh, heck, we don't need assembler, because we can use a binary or hex editor to edit bytes directly in an executable file.

Comment: @Peter Real programmers enter their programs by flipping switches on the control panel or by punching holes by hand on the paper tape.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor has one goal: to establish the class invariant. `class` is usually not just a bunch of member fields and functions: there's usually a relationship between those members that must be established and then held in order for the program to function correctly. E.g. a `Rational` class that consists of `int n` and `size_t d` and represents `n/d` should make sure that `d != 0` and it can't be simplified anymore. Some class members might also be `const`, in which case the last point you can set the value of them (by initialization) is in the constructor.

Comment: @PeteBecker True, corrected the wording.